# Run NPX commands in debug mode

Tags: reactjs, debugging, npm, npx

I got some `npx create-react-app` command stuck without showing any error on the terminal.
So, I require to run `npx` in **debug mode**.

Is there a way to get a **debug** log for `npx` commands to identify the issue?

---

**edit:**
the command I ran:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: are you not getting any error on the terminal?

Comment: no. no any errors

Comment: what's the full command you are running?

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: and.... nothing happens at all? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJnVn.png

Comment: does it hang at that spot forever?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the [answer here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx#run-node-binary-with---inspect). you can debug an `npx` command providing the `--node-options=--inspect` command line argument:

```
npx --node-options=--inspect create-react-app my-app
```

Then in Chrome and you will find a NodeJs debugger button at the top of the Developer Tools panel:

[image]

Click on it and a new Chrome Developer Tools instance will start with your project loaded in the source code.

Search the file you need to debug (either in the **tree view** or using the **quick search** `Cmd/Ctrl-O` feature) and place a breakpoint in the Developer Tools editor.

Then restart the `npx` command and start troubleshooting the `create-react-app` module.

Comment: Since npm 7 `--node-arg` has been replaced by `--node-options` so you should do:

`npx --node-options="--inspect" your-script`

In this case:

`npx --node-options="--inspect" create-react-app my-app`

Comment: And to have the process wait for the debugger to attach *and* keep it paused before executing the very first statement, leverage [*node*'s `--inspect-brk`](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/getting-started/debugging#command-line-options); e.g. `npx --node-options=--inspect-brk create-react-app my-app`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know which argument you can pass to `npx` but you can do it with `npm run`:

`npm -dd run create-react-app my-app`