# next dev server only serves html (no scripts or assets, replicated with stock create-next-app)

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, next.js, npx

To replicate my issue, I created a next app template folder with
`npx create-next-app`
(Version 13.1.6==latest, all default options, Node v18.14.0==LTS)
and when I try to run it with
`npm run dev`
it loads HTML files like index.tsx, but 404s on all assets and scripts.

The same thing happens with `npm run build/start`.

Reproduced the issue on both Chrome and Firefox
(no extensions or adblockers of any sort)
with create-next-app@latest and @12.4.3.
**The issue does not reproduce on Docker though** (node:alpine-current).

[network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqZqA.png)
[console tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/optmR.png)

Comment: Did you try `npx create-next-app@latest` as per [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/create-next-app)?

Comment: Yeah, 13.1.6 is latest

Comment: Sounds like something you should raise as a bug

Comment: Don't think so, I'm getting the same problem with create-next-app@12.3.4, so it's definitely something in my machine.

Comment: See if this helps ~ [Run NPX commands in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61210949/283366)

Comment: Share your project files structure

Comment: Can you add your folder structure? Routes in next are based on file path. So if you want a `/about` page, you'll need to create a `about.js` in the `pages` folder.

Comment: It's the default create-next-app skeleton, I changed nothing. Tried it on Docker (node:alpine-current) to see if I was going mad: nope, works fine on docker.

Comment: So just pages/index.tsx. You can see what fails to load in the question screenshots at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

It was a file naming issue. Apparently Next mishandles your files if there are weird characters in the *absolute* filepaths. I suspect a lot of questions/issues of the sort "brand new create-next-app routes not resolving" have to do with this.